# Проблема с динамическим созданием обьектов

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

У меня есть класс:

```
class TTable {
TTable(TRow *R, int max);//конструктор с параметрами
}
```

TRow это другой класс.
Что бы просто создать один объект ясное дело делаю так:

```
TTable table(row,max); //вызов конструктора с параметрами
```

Что бы динамически создавать обьекты:

```
TTable *table = new TTable(row, max);
```

Но что делать если мне нужно несколько раз создавать объект?
Делал так:

```
TTable *table = new TTable[5];
```

Но в таком случае ведь не будет передано конструктору никаких значений.
Я так понимаю нужно что-то наподобии этого:

```
TTable *table = new TTable(row, max)[5];
```

Но это не работает.
Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для динамического массива стоит воспользоваться вектором, у которого есть конструктор с числом элементов и значением по умолчанию.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class TTable {
    int max_;
public:
    TTable(int m, int x):max_(m+x){};//конструктор с параметрами
    void print() const { std::cout << max_; }
};
int main()
{
    TTable t(5,4);

    std::vector<TTable> v(5, { 7,3 });

    for (const auto& tt : v) {
        tt.print();
        std::cout << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Для простоты иллюстрации - я заменил один из параметров конструктора на инт.